# Why is a hole a time-reversed electron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, symmetry

I am trying to understand a paper where the hole wavefunction is transformed into the electron wavefunction in a semiconductor using the time-reversal operator. None of my books mention this concept so I am looking for an explanation or a source which covers it. Specifically, I am wondering if it can be explained in terms of creation and annihilation operators (e.g. the creation of a hole is just the annihilation of an electron).

Comment: Hmmmmm.... An electron in the valence band can be turned into (electron in conduction band + hole in valence band), the basis for detailed balance and understanding carrier concentrations in semiconductors. So, in my mind, the creation of a hole is not just the annihilation of an electron - that electron goes into the conduction band.

Comment: Well yes, but I mean the hole creation operator is just the electron annihilation operator. Of course, in an actual state this must be accompanied by another electron creation operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that if $\psi$ is a plane wave moving in one direction then $T\psi$ (where $T$ is the time reversal operator) describes a plane wave moving in the opposite direction. As well as, acting $T$ on the spin-up state, we obtain the spin-down state and vice versa.
That's it! the time reversal operator converts the electron state to the hole state.
Note that the hole is nothing but an electron void. If the electron moves to the right, its vacancy moves to the left, and if the electron is spin-up, its void is spin-down.

Answer (score 0):

Feynman's take on this in (I think) his Dirac Memorial Lecture used the CPT theorem as follows: time T is reversed by putting a negative sign in front of the T in CPT. Then he says that it's OK to imagine moving that negative sign off the T (making time run forwards again) to the C, flipping its charge- which then represents the particle as moving forward in time with an opposite charge.